# Force a specific user or application to user a specific java version

Tags: redhat, java, rhel6, versioning

Bear with me, I'm new to sysadmin stuff. We have a server running RHEL 6 (2.6.32). We have a Pentaho application that interacts with the server as a `pentaho` user, and we have a `team` user under whose home directory most of our work is stored (we have reasons and are working on separate logins for this).

The problem is that the `pentaho` user can no longer save files to the `team` user's directory, despite never having an issue with this before. Nothing has changed as far as permissions are concerned.

It appears to be an issue with the version of Java (looks like JDK 1.8.0 got installed) that the user/application is using, so my question is this: how can I control the specific version of Java used by or seen by a specific user or application? How can I tell what versions of JDK are available?

Comment: It is indeed a very vague question, you could improve it by including the installed versions and software (if you don't know them, then include the questions as how to find out). Also specify what do you mean by a "pentaho user", I'm assuming it's the process user for the pentaho system, but it might be a user within pentaho who is trying to upload. You should also specify how did you install java.

Comment: @Leo thanks for the suggestions. I made some improvements to the question. I hope it is clearer now...

Comment: Add/change values of the `$PATH` and `$JAVA_HOME` to appropriate values in the appropriate places to control a single user or a specific application/service on start up

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Red Hat's documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Installation_Guide/sect-use_alternatives_to_set_default_JDK.html):

> `/usr/sbin/alternatives` is a tool for managing different software
>   packages that provide the same functionality. Red Hat Enterprise Linux
>   uses /usr/sbin/alternatives to ensure that only one Java Development
>   Kit is set as the system default at one time.

You might be able to see and configure multiple versions of Java using the **alternatives** utility, as **root** or with **sudo**.

Configure java:

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

For the compiler:

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --config javac
```

But this will set the default java for the system, not for a specific user or application, which might have it's custom settings.